# how to start master robot from my linux laptop

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: I am new to ROS . I am trying my level best to understand the tutorial and follow the instructions.

-- Robot ROS MASTER IP = 192.168.1.3

-- Linux Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS indigo installed IP address  = 192.168.1.68

After editing hosts file and bashrc file in both Robot and Laptop to as per instructions given in
http://nootrix.com/software/ros-networking/. I was able to see topics and use RVIZ to see topics on my laptop. Ping between master and laptop is all good.

My question here is in above network setup. I still need to go into Robot and start roscore. Only then I will be able to see topics and the rest on my laptop.

What is the command or setup required such that . From my laptop terminal I should be able to start roscore/master inside Robot. Is there a way to do so.

Please help me .!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261967/how-to-start-master-robot-from-my-linux-laptop/) by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using SSH as explained in the tutorial you linked to? This would allow you to ssh into your robot and start whatever you would like from your laptop terminal.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on 2017-05-19**:
I tried ssh this time. I made mistake earlier of not using the "username" of robot PC while ssh robotpc@robotcompurtername. That was the mistake. I was using the username of Linux PC user name.